# Extract Certain String after Some Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `customer_info` in which a column `PrintData` which contains many information. I would like to get Transaction id from that column.

The column data look like this:

```
    <Line28>.TVR: 4000008000</Line28>
    <Line29>.IAD: 06020103649D00</Line29>
    <Line30>.TSI: E800</Line30>
    <Line31>.ARC: 00</Line31>
    <Line32>.CVM: PIN VERIFIED</Line32>
    <Line33>.TRAN ID: 000000000075169</Line33>
```

I would like to get only `000000000075169`  i.e. `TRAN ID:`

I have tried this as:

```
SUBSTRING(PrintData,CHARINDEX('TRAN ID: ',PrintData),CHARINDEX('</Li',PrintData))
```

but it is not giving write answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @z NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    <Line28>.TVR: 4000008000</Line28>
    <Line29>.IAD: 06020103649D00</Line29>
    <Line30>.TSI: E800</Line30>
    <Line31>.ARC: 00</Line31>
    <Line32>.CVM: PIN VERIFIED</Line32>
    <Line33>.TRAN ID: 000000000075169</Line33>
    '

    SELECT SUBSTRING(@z, CHARINDEX('TRAN ID: ', @z) + 9 -- offset charindex by 9 characters to omit the 'TRAN ID: '
                       , CHARINDEX('</Li', @z, CHARINDEX('TRAN ID: ', @z))-CHARINDEX('TRAN ID: ', @z) - 9) -- find the </Li AFTER the occurence of TRAN ID, and subract 9 to account for the offset
```

Yields 000000000075169.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please with the following query.

```
DECLARE @PrintData AS VARCHAR (200) = '<Line33>.TRAN ID: 000000000075169</Line33>';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@PrintData, 
                 CHARINDEX('TRAN ID: ', @PrintData) + LEN('TRAN ID: '), 
                 CHARINDEX('</Li',@PrintData) - (CHARINDEX('TRAN ID: ', @PrintData) + LEN('TRAN ID: '))
                 );
```

The syntax is `SUBSTRING (expression, start_position, length)`

**UPDATE:**

As per the comment by MarcinJ, for the multiple instance of `</Line`, the folllowing query will work.

```
DECLARE @PrintData VARCHAR(2000) = '
    <Line28>.TVR: 4000008000</Line28>
    <Line29>.IAD: 06020103649D00</Line29>
    <Line30>.TSI: E800</Line30>
    <Line31>.ARC: 00</Line31>
    <Line32>.CVM: PIN VERIFIED</Line32>
    <Line33>.TRAN ID: 000000000075169</Line33>
    ';

DECLARE @FindString AS VARCHAR (20) = 'TRAN ID: ';
DECLARE @LenFindString AS INT = LEN(@FindString);

SELECT SUBSTRING(@PrintData, 
                 CHARINDEX(@FindString, @PrintData) + @LenFindString, 
                 CHARINDEX('</Line', @PrintData, CHARINDEX(@FindString, @PrintData)) - (CHARINDEX(@FindString, @PrintData) + @LenFindString)
                 );
```

Comment: It won't work if there are multiple </Line> tags in the column and TRAN ID is not the first, because `CHARINDEX('</LI', @PrintData)` will return the first result.

Comment: @Dev I have updated the code for the multiple end instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `APPLY` :

```
select @PrintData AS Original_string, 
       substring(tran_id, 1, charindex('</', tran_id) -1) as Tran_ID
from ( values ( substring(PrintData, charindex('TRAN ID:', PrintData) + 8, len(PrintData)) )
     ) t(tran_id);
```